# sObject type 'PermissionSetAssignment' is not supported

Tags: soql, api, soap-api, permission-sets

```
SELECT AssigneeId,Id,PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = '< id >' AND PermissionSetId = '< id >'
```

On firing above query using API (/services/data/v20.0/), i am getting error mentioned below:

> Array(
>        [message] => sObject type 'PermissionSetAssignment' is not supported
>        [errorCode] => INVALID_TYPE  )

I have tried changing the API versions like `(/services/data/v22.0/)` and `(/services/data/v40.0/)` but no luck...

what do i need to change in salesforce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below callout URL:

```
/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+AssigneeId,Id,PermissionSet.Name+FROM+PermissionSetAssignment
```

With Id:

```
/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+AssigneeId,Id,PermissionSet.Name+FROM+PermissionSetAssignment+WHERE+id='0Pa300000000pVsCAI'
```

It works perfect in workbench. You may be providing  binding in wrong way. Check that as well.

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right this is absolutely working as expected using workbench but when tried the same with php curl and it's giving me the error..

Comment: Please check curl end point and headers and match with Workbench, there must be a difference @NailDavid

Comment: @NailDavid PermissionSetAssignment is available in 22.0 and higher; it is most likely that you didn't set the version correctly in your PHP code. 22.0 or any higher version would suffice.